# C# inheritance generic classes with constraints

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, generic-constraints

So, I have a interface:

```
interface A<SomeType>
{
    SomeType Abc(SomeType);
    .....
}
```

and I have an class:

```
class B<ShouldBeClassA<AnyType>> 
     where ShouldBeClassA<AnyType> : A<AnyType>
{ ShouldBeClassA<AnyType> someVariable; .....}
```

But this is causes syntax error's, what i want, is to force someVariable to be derivative of

```
A<AnyType>
```

so i can do that:

```
class B......
{
    ....
    void Method()
    {
        someVariable.Abc(anyTypeVariable);
    }
 ......}
```

Can u pls tell me, how to fix that?

Here is the actual code:

```
public interface IGenericTeacher<Genome<GenomeType>>
    where Genome<GenomeType> : IGenome<GenomeType>
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Pass the tests and save the results.
    /// </summary>
    void PassTests();

    /// <summary>
    /// Passing generation, according to the results.
    /// </summary>
    void PassGeneration();

}


public interface IGenome<GenomeType>
{
   .......
```

Comment: `where ShouldBeClassA<AnyType>> : A<AnyType>` has an extra `>`, that's your syntax error.

Comment: C# does not have templates. It has Generics. The generic type argument can be constrained, which is what `where` is. Ive suggested an edit to the title and tags to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface should be:

```
public interface IGenericTeacher<T> where T : IGenome<T>
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: That mistake ive made was cuz i was hurry, so, ive added the actual code, that's not working